# Enabling Spring Security makes Swagger output text/plain instead of HTML

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-maven-plugin

Swagger works!  I can interact with http://localhost:8090/sdoc.jsp and everything is fine.

I add the following to pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also add the following two files:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if( !Authenticate.authenticate(name, password) )
            return null;

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()

            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
                .httpBasic()
                ;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

At this point if I visit the same URL that was previously working I now instead get a response type of "text/plain" and instead of a pretty HTML looking browser I see source code.

If I revert the change and remove the two files from project and remove JAR file it works again.

How do I get Spring Security and Swagger to play nice?  What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is due to Spring-Security's effect on the content-type headers (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html#headers-content-type-options).

From the docs -

> Historically browsers, including Internet Explorer, would try to guess the content type of a request using content sniffing. This allowed browsers to improve the user experience by guessing the content type on resources that had not specified the content type. For example, if a browser encountered a JavaScript file that did not have the content type specified, it would be able to guess the content type and then execute it.
>
> The problem with content sniffing is that this allowed malicious users to use polyglots (i.e. a file that is valid as multiple content types) to execute XSS attacks. For example, some sites may allow users to submit a valid postscript document to a website and view it. A malicious user might create a postscript document that is also a valid JavaScript file and execute a XSS attack with it.

Again, from the docs, in order to override the default -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      // ...
      .headers()
        .contentTypeOptions();
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback and the added information. I hope it'll help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I figured it was something along these lines.  Thanks so much

When I tried this and it started working

```
.headers()
    .disable()
```

I narrowed the default contentTypeOptions down to..

```
.headers()
        //.contentTypeOptions()   // If this is uncommented it fails.
        .xssProtection()
        .cacheControl()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
        .frameOptions()
        .and()
```